# XML file parsing using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, file, parsing

i need to pull data out of an xml file based on certain field values. the xml file is set up like this

```
<main>
 <report>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <ID>1234</ID>
  <field>
   <acel>80</acel>
   <decel>50</decel>
   <left>20</left>
   <right>10</right>
   <category>1-10</category>
  </field> 
  <field>
   <acel>30</acel>
   <decel>54</decel>
   <left>12</left>
   <right>13</right>
   <category>10-20</category>
  </field> 
  <field>
   <acel>34</acel>
   <decel>210</decel>
   <left>27</left>
   <right>9</right>
   <category>20-30</category>
  </field>
 </report>
 <report>
 ....
 </report>
</main>
```

I currently have the following:

```
var query = doc.Descendants("report")
           .Select(raw => new
           {
               version = (string)raw.Element("version"), 
               tcid = (string)raw.Element("id"),
               forces =    raw.Element("field").Elements("acel").Select(acel => (int)acel).ToList()

           });
```

I need to search the file for reports that match specific ID's and specific versions, and then get the accsociated fields acel, decel, left, right etc.

ex I need to find a report for ID 1234 and version 1.0, and have all the field values 80, 50 etc. Any help is great. I have code that returns ID and version already but I'm having trouble getting all the values of field based on version and ID.

Thanks.

Comment: There is pretty good documentation on doing all this with lots of samples :- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a hint:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var fields = xDoc
    .Descendants("report")
    .Where(r => (int)r.Element("ID") == 1234)
    .Elements("field")
    .Select(f => new
        {
            Acel = f.Element("acel").Value,
            Decel = f.Element("decel").Value,
        }
    );
```

We first fetch `report` nodes and filter those to the ones matching `ID` of `1234` - that leaves us with first one from your example. Next, we query all the `field` nodes within this report, and extract new objects basing on field values. Looks <strike>simple</strike> awesome? It really is!

Answer (score 1):

You start by inserting a `.Where()` :

```
var query = doc
        .Descendants("report")
        .Where(r => r.Element("version").Value == "1.0" 
                    && r.Element("ID").Value == "1234") 
        .Select(raw => new
           {
               version = (string)raw.Element("version"), 
               tcid = (string)raw.Element("id"),
               forces = raw.Element("field").Elements("acel")
                          .Select(acel => (int)acel).ToList()

           });
```